# Detect which process is attempting TCP connections

Tags: monitoring, tcp

On my MacBook Pro (Monterey), I was looking at packet captures over a period of a few hours and I noticed that something on my box is, every few minutes, pinging other computers on the local network at port 7000 (sometimes my wife's work computer and sometimes my baby monitor).  The recipients respond to the SYN packets with RST packets, so no connection is being established.  Is there a way to set up some sort of watchdog which identifies which process/executable is attempting the connections when they occur?

Comment: [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) should be able to show what program it is.

Comment: This may be your ["Zero Configuration Networking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking), a.k.a. *Bonjour* at work. My macBookPro (Catalina) has a tool called `nettop` installed at `/usr/bin/nettop`. I've not used it much, but Apple's typical high-quality, up-to-date documentation is available in `man nettop`. But, all kidding aside, there's what appears to be a [useful guide for using `nettop` on a mac available from UT](https://sites.cns.utexas.edu/oit-blog/blog/how-monitor-network-traffic-os-x-mac).

Comment: @GordonDavisson: LittleSnitch claims to monitor *Internet traffic*; the OP is asking about traffic on his *local* network. Does LittleSnitch capture local traffic also?

Comment: @Seamus - yes, though local is normally covered by two overall allow rules, in & out. You can change this manually.

Comment: @Seamus I don't use it myself, but my understanding is that LittleSnitch monitors IP traffic, whether it's local or routed.

Comment: Little Snitch will help you checking whats going on. It works on all connections, not only on "Internet" ones.